# Laravel display AJAX call JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, laravel-5

Have some data returning from a AJAX call and cant get to output to screen on a live search page

Laravel Controller looks like

```
 // Live Search
    public function searching() {
        $search_keyword = $_POST['search_keyword'];
        $searchClients = DB::table('clients')->where('company', 'like', '%'.$search_keyword.'%')->get();
        return response()->json($searchClients);

    }
```

That works fine and data is coming back and looks like

```
0
:
{id: 58, company: "Havenkey Ltd", con: "2441", engaged: "n", industry: "", status: 27, location: 1444,…}
1
:
{id: 62, company: "V3 Recruitment Ltd", con: "", engaged: "n", industry: "", status: 27,…}
```

Front end is below with the search box and a a results div to display result sin

```
<div class="col-lg-8" style="padding-top: 30px;">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <a href="{{URL::asset('/')}}">Dashboard</a> / Search Clients
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <label for="search">Search</label>
                    <input type="text" class="search_keyword" id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Clients Name">
                </div>
            </form>

            <div id="result">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-2" style="padding-top: 30px;">
    @include('partials.notepad')
</div>
```

and JS looks like this

```
$(".search_keyword").keyup(function () {
    //setup before functions
    var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
    var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example
    var $input = $('#search');

//on keyup, start the countdown
    $input.on('keyup', function () {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    });

//on keydown, clear the countdown
    $input.on('keydown', function () {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    });

//user is "finished typing," do something
    function doneTyping () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/searching",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data){
                    console.log('Here');
                    $('#result').html('');
                    $('#result').append('<select id="res"></select>');
                    $.each(data, function(i,val) {
                        $(document).find('#res').append(
                            $("<option>").text(val.company).val(val.id)
                    )
                });
    }else {
        alert('im not working');
    }
}
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

So all im trying to achieve here is outputting live search results which append the company name to a list which can be selected on click at some point

Comment: Were do you want to display ? And how ?

Comment: In the results div in list which may change to a select dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we need to initiate ajax call only when user is done with typing so it will avoid to initiate ajax call for each character typed in. So to achieve this mechanism,

```
//setup before functions
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example
var $input = $('#myInput');

//on keyup, start the countdown
$input.on('keyup', function () {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$input.on('keydown', function () {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
  //here we will call the ajax function.
}
```

And there in your ajax call, change the `success` callback like mentioned below:

```
success: function (data) {
       if(data){
           console.log('Here');
           $('#result').html('');
           $('#result').append('<select id="res"></select>');
           $.each(data, function(i,val) {
                $(document).find('#res').append(
                $("<option>").text(val.company).val(val.id);
                });
           });
       }else {
           alert('im not working');
       }
}
```

Comment: so im getting app.js:833 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonResult is not defined

Comment: So on every key up its giving a blank select box , no errors at all in the console

Comment: Can you see any error in developer console of browser ?

Comment: Yeah no console errors at all just produces select boxes on every key up

Comment: oh, yes, I got it why its appending multiple select. Sorry @GrahamMorbyDojo for trouble, let me fix the code properly. I will update it soon.

Comment: ok @GrahamMorbyDojo, check the update answer. I have changed a lot. Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: so added new stuff and got Uncaught ReferenceError: dataString is not defined

Comment: ofcource, its not defined. You missed to move that from previous code.

Comment: Ignore! I have it!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It certainly puts in a good place to style